# How to change stylesheet with Jquery and Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

Hello I've been trying to solve this problem for quite a while. Back when I was using vanilla html this code seems to work. (Changing from tile view to list view). Now that I have incorporated it in django and the hrefs contains static tags, I dont know how to refer to it in jquery and change its href. Pls help

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "Stylesheets/tileVersion.css"  %}">
```

I want to change it to this css href

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Stylesheets/listVersion.css">
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#listicon').click(function () {
        $('link[href="static/Stylesheets/tileVersion.css"]').attr('href', 'static/Stylesheets/listVersion.css');
    });
    $('#tilesicon').click(function () {
        $('link[href="static/Stylesheets/listVersion.css"]').attr('href', 'static/Stylesheets/tileVersion.css');
    });
```

I want to be able to switch between them if possible. Any kind of help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of two things.

1. You can use static references to load one CSS file over another, by using a if tag in your code getting the css link value (the address/url) from a variable or from a data source.  This compiles during server time.  This also means that only one css is loaded at runtime.  This is static for the client. For example:
2. Same as #1, but you can use an inline if to determine which one goes forward to the client.
3. Lastly, ensure both css files are held within the static process, and maintain your jquery:

   `$('#listicon').click(function () {
       $('link[href="{% static /path/to/first/css/page %}"]').attr('href', '{% static /path/to/first/css/page %}');
   });
   $('#tilesicon').click(function () {
       $('link[href="{% static /path/to/second/css/page %}"]').attr('href', {% static /path/to/second/css/page %});
   });`

   I typed this out of memory, so please bear with me.
   Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you! I'll try this out tomorrow but I think it will work. Quite tired from a whole day of coding

Answer (score 0):

Just put an additional attribute `id` for the link tag. You can remove the current `stylesheet` from `head` and add another one.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="myid" href="../Stylesheets/listVersion.css">

$('#myid').remove();
$('head').append( $( '<link/>', {'rel' : 'stylesheet', 'id': 'myid', 'href':'newlink' } ));
```

Comment: Hello! I get what youre trying to say but how do I load them at the same time in django but only show 1 in client side?

Comment: You have to load only one. The file is served by the server. You load one of them. Static files are always available for public. No matter which one you load in django template, all the static files have their own urls and you can access them anytime. You can change the href attribute in between .

Comment: @Jason If the new css file is not fetched by browser on href attribute change, let me know. We have an alternative.

Comment: yep unfortunately its not working. Its all in one static folder in my django but if I include both they just overlap

Comment: You mean there are classes with same name?

Comment: It just loads the html file and removes my tileversion css completely so I end up with no css. I guess its because of the static tag? The css file in itself is still accessible but its not working quite as I want it to

Comment: So it appears to like this. You changed the href of the link tag. But browser didn't fetch the new style apply it.

Comment: its fetching my css file but its not applying it. Otherwise I'd probably get a 404. This is whats really confusing me

Comment: I have updated my answer, just try it. I hope this will work because instead of just changing an attribute, we are removing the stylesheet and adding another.

Comment: Hello again! sorry I fell asleep. I think this will work only for the vanilla html. Simply changing the attr(href,value) would do the same thing. I need some kind of way around the static tag